# Trying to build lambda function using SAM plugin in visual studio code and trying to connect to MYSQL RDS instance but not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, aws-lambda, sam

I am building lambda function using visual studio code SAM option. I am trying to connect to RDS instance (MYSQL) which is in VPC network. 
I tried connecting using following code. I am not getting any error but it is not connecting to DB. I have searched every where but didn't get any solution. I tried following but didn't worked

```
const fs = require('fs');


    const mysqlssh = require('mysql-ssh');
    mysqlssh.connect(
        {
            host: 'XXX.XXX.XX.XX',
            user: 'ec2-user',
            privateKey: fs.readFileSync('./XXXX-txlarge.pem')
        },
        {
            host: '-staging-instanceXXXXX.rds.amazonaws.com',
            user: 'user',
            password: 'password',
            database: 'db'
        }
    )
    .then(client => {
        client.query('SELECT * FROM users', function (err, results, fields) {
            if (err) throw err
            console.log(results);
            mysqlssh.close()
        })
    })
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I am not getting any but not connecting to DB

Comment: Try to console the client object and show the results

Comment: @sohan I printed object it gave me [Object object] then I tried printing state of connection object (client) it is coming  as disconnected . I am very new to node js and lambda this is my first  lambda function.so please tell me if I am doing anything silly or wrong.

Comment: Could you try `JSON.stringyfy(client )` that object and paste the output. It may contain results of  why it got disconnected
Also check this https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-cannot-connect/

Comment: Also why are you using `mysql-ssh` moudle and why not `mysql`?

Comment: I resolved this problem by using mysql instead of mysql-ssh. I used mysql-ssh because I wanted to connect to RDS in VPC network but I created ssh tunnel in local and then was able to connect to RDS using mysql.

Comment: great, i will post the solution similar to this

Comment: why have you added two host property earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `mysql-ssh` which is tunneling based type of sql connection module try to use simple `mysql` module,

```
const fs = require('fs');   

const mysql = require('mysql');
let connection = mysql.createConnection(
    {
        host: 'XXX.XXX.XX.XX-staging-instanceXXXXX.rds.amazonaws.com',
        user: 'user',
        password: 'password',
        database: 'db'
    }
);

 connection.connect();

 connection.query('SELECT * FROM users', function (err, results, fields) {
       if (err) throw err
        console.log("rows: " + rows);
        context.succeed('Success');
    });
```

PS: You might  need to some of code as per you needs, but this is what you should try doing.

Comment: @Sonali Also it will be great if you upvote this answer, as this complete the acceptance process